# iOS: How to invalidate or kill every timer in activity in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, timer, nstimer

I would like to stop every timers in my app. The problem is that I put timer that launches Web Services, and even if I put some invalidate, it seems that when I close the ViewController, the Timer are still in activity. I can check that there is a problem very easily because when I print the _currentDate, I can see that there is several currentDate that are been launching and I only must see only one currentDate (the one I choose in a label).

May be it is because the reinit of the timer is launched from a DispatchQueue.main.async ? So how can I stop it?

```
fileprivate var _refreshTimer:Timer?

func reinitTimer()
{
    stopTimer()

    if _refreshTimer == nil {
    _refreshTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(TIMER_PLANNING_REFRESH), target: self, selector: #selector(PlanningViewController.reloadDataTick(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}

func stopTimer()
{
    if _refreshTimer != nil {
    _refreshTimer!.invalidate()
    _refreshTimer = nil
    }
}

func reloadDataTick(_ timer:Timer)
{
    // WebService launching with the current date that is choosen in a label with popover.

    DAL.sharedInstance.getPlanningInformation(_currentDate) { (models, error) -> Void in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if error == nil
                {
                   ...

                   self.reinitTimer()
                }
           }

       }
```

To resume my problem, the reloadDataTick function never stops and is launched everytime, with all the date I choose, even with the invalidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious remark : remove the fileprivate property. Only keep

```
 var _refreshTimer:Timer?
```

You can have some information about private / fileprivate in Swift3:
https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-the-difference-between-private-and-fileprivate-in-swift-3/